# Why is acr_values not passed to POST /connect/token on Identity Server 4?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect, openid

I am trying to authenticate a user that is related to an existed tenant. but the acr_values was not passed. [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hUvvA.png)

Comment: I think acr_values should be sent as a query parameter

Comment: What does your `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` implementation look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've added __tenant in the header with tenant id as value.

Answer (score 0):

You can access additional params via the `ResourceOwnerPasswordValidationContext.Request.Raw` property inside your `IResourceOwnerPasswordValidator` implementation.

Since `acr_values` doesn't really apply to this grant type you might be better off just passing a custom parameter called `tenant` and picking it up from the `Request.Raw` propery in the validator.